# Why wont my file open and how can I fix it?

Tags: c, file-handling, readonly

Whenever I run my program the screen prints "cannot open file *filename*". I followed guidelines and methodology in my lecture notes and really can't figure out why it won't open. Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define READONLY "r"

int main (void)
{
  FILE *ipfile;
  char filename[FILENAME_MAX+1];
  int *unsorted_details;
  int elements;

  printf("Enter the name of the input file:\n");
  scanf("%s", filename);

  if((ipfile=fopen(filename, READONLY)) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s. \n", filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  } 
  if (fscanf(ipfile, "%d", &elements) != 1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't read object details from %s\n", 
filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if ((unsorted_details=(int *)malloc(elements * sizeof(int))) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory.\n");
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  /* Reading elements from file into unsorted array*/
    int i;
  for (i=0; i<elements; i++){
    if(!fscanf(ipfile, "%d", &unsorted_details[i])){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading element %d of the list\n", i+1);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   }
  fclose(ipfile);
  free(unsorted_details);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: the file probably doesn't exist in the current directory.

Comment: Sorry i dont know what you mean by file directory, how can I amend this?

Comment: put the file in the same directory containing the exe file and give the extension of the file as well while giving the input. try it once..

Comment: try to input the full file path (absolute). also try to print `getcwd()` you may not be in the dir you think you are.

Comment: You should print the actual error. Read fopen docs (google for example "man fopen"). Also print the actual file name, and current working directory.

Comment: When a function fails, have your `fprintf` calls print `strerror(errno)`.  That will tell you why the function failed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I have moved the .txt file to the same folder as the exe and its still not working?

Answer (score 1):

Most library functions make use of an external variable called `errno` which is set when one of those functions fails and indicates the reason for the failure.

You can get a textual description of the error message either by calling `perror`, which prints the error message to `stderr`, or you can call `strerror(errno)` which returns a `char *` which points to the error message that you can subsequently put in your own error message.

In the case of the failed call to `fopen`, change your error message to the following:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open %s: %s \n", filename, strerror(errno));
```

You can make similar changes to your other error messages.  Once you do this, you'll know why the function failed and take appropriate action.